# Colisão e reação Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tenho uma duvida em um script, estou criando um jogo feito no unity 3d. A duvida e a seguinte, como faço para identificar a colisão entre 2 objetos e adicionar uma ação de pulo a um desses objetos, se alguém poder ajudar agradeço muito.

Código - não funciona:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 jump = new Vector2(0,200);
     public Collider2D coli;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Transform tmf;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        tmf = GetComponent<Transform>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
     void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "piso")
        {
            //rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            // rb.AddForce(jump);
            Vector2 vt2 = tmf.localPosition;
            vt2.y = 2f;
            tmf.localPosition = vt2;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é simplesmente trocar `Collider2D` para `Collision2D`.

Answer (score 1):

Como o Pablo disse troque o Collider2D por Collision2D e verifique se o seu objeto piso esta com a tag piso.